# What are the implications of Flask-MQTT statement, "Flask-MQTT is currently not suitable for the use with multiple worker instances?"

Tags: python, flask, mqtt, worker

I am planning to implement a Python REST API using Flask. I plan to use the Waitress web server. I want the REST API to interact with a long-running app using MQTT. I was planning to use Flask-MQTT. I noticed [a statement](https://flask-mqtt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#multiple-workers):

> Flask-MQTT is currently not suitable for the use with multiple worker instances.

I have tried, without success, to gain an understanding of what this statement implies for my use.

I noticed that there is a Flask-MQTT extension, flask-multimqtt, that was developed to address the issue of not Flask-MQTT not being suitable for use with multiple worker instances.

I have searched the internet to gain an understanding of the implications of the statement, "Flask-MQTT is currently not suitable for the use with multiple worker instances." I have not found anything that sheds light on the statement.

I have a few questions:

1. Is there a configuration for Waitress that allows it to be used with Flask-MQTT?
2. Is there a reason not to use Flask-MQTT?
3. Would using Flask and MQTT from separate packages eliminate the concern of using multiple worker instances?

Comment: The statement means that Flask-MQTT is not designed to handle concurrent calls (i.e. if two threads call `Publish` the results will be unpredictable. If you can ensure that no concurrent calls are made (via the design of your application, for example [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) messages to be published and do this in one thread) then it will work OK. `flask-multimqtt` [wraps](https://git.sr.ht/~martijnbraam/Flask-MultiMQTT/tree/master/item/flask_multimqtt/__init__.py#L110) `paho` calls with a [`lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects).